# SOLR how to limit the search content in solr query

Tags: solr

i want to search the words upto particular line and not beyond that using solr query. i have tried proximity match but it didnt worked. my data is like

> Blockquote"Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 09:36:44 GMT\nCache-Control: private\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\nContent-Encoding: gzip\nVary: Accept-Encoding\nP3P: CP=%20CURo TAIo IVAo IVDo ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM STA OUR%20\nX-Powered-By: ASP.NET\nContent-Length: 570       \nKeep-Alive: timeout=120\nConnection: Keep-Alive\n\n[{%20rows%20:[],%20index%20:[],%20folders%20:[[%20Inbox%20,%20Inbox%20,%20%20,1,1,0,0,0,%20Inbox%20,0,0,%20none%20,0],[%20Drafts%20,%20Drafts%20,%20%20,1,1,0,0,0,%20Drafts%20,0,0,%20none%20,0],[%20Sent%20,%20Sent%20,%20%20,1,1,0,0,11,%20Sent%20,1,0,%20none%20,0],[%20Spam%20,%20Spam%20,%20%20,1,1,0,0,0,%20Spam%20,1,0,%20none%20,0],[%20Deleted%20,%20Trash%20,%20%20,1,1,0,7,9,%20Deleted%20,1,0,%20none%20,0],[%20Saved%20,%20Saved Mail%20,%20%20,1,1,0,0,0,%20Saved%20,1,0,%20none%20,0],[%20SavedIMs%20,%20Saved Chats%20,%20Saved%20,2,1,0,0,0,%20SavedIMs%20,1,0,%20none%20,0]],%20fcsupport%20:true,%20hasNewMsg%20:false,%20totalItems%20:0,%20isSuccess%20:true,%20foldersCanMoveTo%20:[%20Sent%20,%20Spam%20,%20Deleted%20,%20Saved%20,%20SavedIMs%20],%20indexStart%20:0}]POST /38664-816/aol-6/en-us/common/rpc/RPC.aspx?user=hl1lkgReIh&transport=xmlhttp&r=0.019667088333411797&a=GetMessageList&l=31211 HTTP/1.1\nHost: mail.aol.com\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\nReferer: http://mail.aol.com/38664-816/aol-6/en-us/Suite.aspx\nContent-Length: 452\nCookie: mbox=PC#1405514778803-136292.22_06#1407395182|session#1406185366924-436868#1406187442|check#true#1406185642; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D55C638B5F089E6FB-19ACDEED1644FD86%7C1469344726539%3B%20s_getnr%3D1406186326569-Repeat%7C1469258326569%3B%20s_nrgvo%3DRepeat%7C1469258326571%3B; s_vi=[CS]v1|29E33A0D051D366F-60000105200097FF[CE]; UNAUTHID=1.5efb4a11934a40b8b5272557263dadfe.88c5; RSP_COOKIE=type=30&name=YWxzaGFraWIyMDE0&sn=MzRb%2FjjHIe8odpr%2FfxZR2g%3D%3D&stype=0&agrp=M; LTState=ver:5&lav:22&un:*UQo5AwAnAytffwJSYg%3d%3d&sn:*UQo5AwAnAytffwJSYg%3d%3d&uv:AOL&lc:en-us&ud:aol.com&ea:*UQo5AwAnAytffwJSCAsnWWoJASZL&prmc:825345&mt:6&ams:1&cmai:365&snt:0&vnop:False&mh:core-mia002b.r1000.mail.aol.com&br:100&wm:mail.aol.com&ckd:.mail.aol.com&ckp:%2f&ha:1NGRuUTRRxGFF2s5A4JwkuCT43Q%3d&; aolweatherlocation=10003; DataLayer=cons%3D6.107%26coms%3D629; grvinsights=69f3a2bb86ed3cd31aa1d14a1ce9e845; CUNAUTHID=1.5efb4a11934a40b8b5272557263dadfe.88c5; s_sess=%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3Daolcmp%253D%252526pid%25253Dcmp%2525253A%25252520Help%25252520%2525257C%25252520View%25252520Article%2525253A%25252520Clear%25252520cookies%2525252C%25252520cache%2525252C%25252520history%25252520and%25252520footprints%252526pidt%25253D1%252526oid%25253Dhttp%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fwebmail.aol.com%2525252F%2525253F_AOLLOCAL%2525253Dmail%252526ot%25253DA%2526aolsnssignin%253D%252526pid%25253Dsso%25252520%2525253A%25252520login%252526pidt%25253D1%252526oid%25253DSign%25252520In%252526oidt%25253D3%252526ot%25253DSUBMIT%3B; L7Id=31211; Context=ver:3&sid:923f783b-bc6e-4edf-87c9-e52f19b3ce67&rt:STANDARD&i:f&ckd:.mail.aol.com&ckp:%2f&ha:X80Ku4ffRKsOVSwgmEVPCfpfxeU%3d&; IDP_A=s-1-V0c3QiuO6BzQ5S6_u3s0brfUqMCktezAz7sWlVfHD90omIijDXRrMJkSM-9-xcnUcSTnXbcZ1aUCgvfuToVeJihcftKY5KtsC_nB7Y9qf6P0xUnNfCIAmWVtRf4ctSQ9JwRIzHa40dhFuULwYLu3NUPTxckeFUFAzcSS4hrmb4grhEtyOGp0qV5rIKtjs4u8; MC_CMP_ESK=NonSense; SNS_AA=asrc=2&sst=1406185424&type=0; _utd=gd#MzRb%2FjjHIe8odpr%2FfxZR2g%3D%3D|pr#a|st#sns.webmail.aol.com|uid#; Auth=ver:22&uas:*UQo5AwAnAytffwJSZAskRiwLBSIDWVpVXxVTVwJCLFxdSnpHUWBbeV1jcikERgl6CEYLJUweGUhdFQQLW1h%2bBAZRcllWfVl8VH4DUmRaZARoPhw%2bBFBA&idl:0&un:*UQo5AwAnAytffwJSYg%3d%3d&at:SNS&sn:*UQo5AwAnAytffwJSYg%3d%3d&wim:%252FwQCAAAAAAAEk2ihy%252BE4MMebm4R1jvxY07zNZhFOHSz2EFBnsNdOAUsl8QyZceo54kWYZ4vwVayLFF7w&sty:0&ud:aol.com&uid:hl1lkgReIh&ss:635417678271359104&svs:SNS_AA%7c1406185424&la:635417687268954835&aat:A&act:M&br:100&cbr:AOL&mt:&pay:0&mbt:G&uv:AOL&lc:en-us&bid:1&acd:1403348988&pix:3829&prmc:825345&relm:aol&mah:%2\nConnection: keep-alive\n"

and want to search Content-Type: application/json from the data and not beyond this line. I have tried

> http://192.168.0.164:8983/solr/collection_with_all_details/select?q=Content%3A*Content-Type*json*&wt=json&indent=true

but it searches in entire content. i need to limit the search content

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in this case. You can check `highlighter` to return that first 200 characters in highlighting response.

May be you need think of writting a custom response writer which can help on this.

One more option cab be creating additional field with `indexed="false"` `stored="true"` will be more efficient.

Create your original field `indexed="true"` `stored="false"`, your index size will be diminished. New copy field will be `indexed="false"` `stored="true"`.

```
<copyField source="text" dest="textShort" maxChars="200"/>
```

Check if this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should really, really pre-process your data to just index the part that you're going to use. Doing it after the fact will not be a good solution, as you'll have most of the content in the index already, and you're looking for a separator that's not positioned in one specific byte location (which is what `maxChars` would be able to do).

Depending on how you're indexing, you can either do it in the indexing step (regextransformer, in your own code using SolrJ, etc), or do it in the analysis step of the code, by using something like a patternreplacefilter. That would allow you to remove anything after the header you're looking for.

That way you should be able to index the content into one `header` field and one `body` field for example, depending on your need.